# Java-How to make template method from example?

Tags: java, swing, templates, progress

I have one problem, I have progress bar done and i now want to implement progress bar to work with search.. I mean i want from progress bar to load until my results don't show up on my search result window. I have a lot of troubles and I do this for like few days.. I hope someone will edit my code or give ma a point to solution how I can fix this issue. I am very sad because I have to bother you but I don't have any other solution.

One more time, I need to make template method of that method to implement it easily to other places in code... Please guys help me i don't understand how it need to be done. Thank you one more time.

### This is code:

```
// but data will be stored in here...
hiddenResultValues = new HashMap < String, Vector < String >> ();

Vector < String > columnNames = field.getResultColumnNames();

final Vector < Vector < String >> tableContent = new Vector < Vector < String >> ();


int size = results.size();
final double stepSize = 100 / size;
//starts long running task off of EDT.
final Vector < QueryResult < Contact >> resultsFin = results;
final SearchField fieldFin = field;
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("progress bar example");
        final JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int z = 0;
                for (QueryResult < Contact > q: resultsFin) {
                    z = (int)(z + stepSize);
                    final int j = z;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            progress.setValue(j);
                        }
                    });
                    if (application.isAueTool() && ((q.getQueryResult().getBusinessCategory().contains("K-tronik") &&
                            !q.getQueryResult().getBusinessCategory().contains("AUE")) || (q.getQueryResult().getBusinessCategory().compareTo("Mitarbeiter") == 0) || (q.getQueryResult().getBusinessCategory().compareTo("Kandidat") == 0))) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Vector < String > values = new Vector < String > ();

                    for (String s: fieldFin.getResultColumns()) {
                        values.add(q.getTableEntryForColumn(s));
                    }

                    tableContent.add(values);

                    contacts.add(q.getQueryResult());

                }
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(progress);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
// store hidden results
for (String s: field.getHiddenResultColumns())
    hiddenResultValues.put(s, new Vector < String > ());

for (QueryResult < Contact > q: results) {
    for (String s: field.getHiddenResultColumns()) {
        hiddenResultValues.get(s).add(q.getTableEntryForColumn(s));
    }
}

resultsPanel.remove(resultsScrollPane);

searchResults = new SearchResultTable(tableContent, columnNames, contacts, false);
sorter = new TableSorter(searchResults.getModel());
Vector < Color > colors = new Vector < Color > ();
for (Contact tempCon: contacts) {
    colors.add(Color.white);
}
searchResults = new SearchResultTable(sorter, contacts, sorter, colors, 18, false);

sorter.addMouseListenerToHeaderInTable(searchResults);

searchResults.addKeyListener(this);
searchResults.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
searchResults.setSize(new Dimension(GUIConstants.LEFT_PANEL_WIDTH, GUIConstants.SEARCH_RESULTS_HEIGHT));
searchResults.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(GUIConstants.LEFT_PANEL_WIDTH, GUIConstants.SEARCH_RESULTS_HEIGHT));
searchResults.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(0, 0);
int rowIndex = 0;
for (Contact tempCon: contacts) {
    if (tempCon.getContactStatus().equals("Blocked") || tempCon.getContactStatus().equals("Inactive"))
        searchResults.updateColorOfRow(rowIndex, Color.red);
    if (tempCon.getContactStatus().equals("Frozen"))
        searchResults.updateColorOfRow(rowIndex, Color.orange);
    if (tempCon.getBusinessCategory().equals("Kandidat") && (application.getDSConsentDate(tempCon.getEntryKey()) == null))
        searchResults.updateColorOfRow(rowIndex, Color.orange);
    rowIndex++;
}
// set column widths
for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++) {
    TableColumn column = searchResults.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
    try {
        column.setPreferredWidth(field.getColumnWidths().get(i));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        column.setPreferredWidth(GUIConstants.LEFT_PANEL_WIDTH / columnNames.size());
    }
}

resultsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(searchResults);
resultsScrollPane.setSize(new Dimension(GUIConstants.LEFT_PANEL_WIDTH, GUIConstants.SEARCH_RESULTS_HEIGHT));
resultsScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(GUIConstants.LEFT_PANEL_WIDTH, GUIConstants.SEARCH_RESULTS_HEIGHT));

resultsPanel.add(resultsScrollPane);

numberOfResults.setText(tableContent.size() + " Treffer");

validate();
}
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(application, "Während der Suche ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!" + "\n" + ex.getLocalizedMessage(), "Information", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(application, "Bitte geben Sie einen Suchbegriff ein", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

searchResults.requestFocus();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && e.getSource().equals(searchResults)) {
        showDetails();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        performSearch();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Q && e.getSource().equals(searchResults)) {
        showCandidateQuickOverview();
    }
}
```

Thank you so much.

Edit:
p.s. 
I want to take a progress bar from there and make template method from it so i can implement it easily somewhere else.
+15 rep who make me template method from this code for progress bar. That is the only way i can learn how to do it ...

EDIT 2 : This is only progress bar code : i post much more code because i thought you need to take a look down too. Also my progress bar works by results , when he fetching results from database the progress bar getting loaded to 100% , when progress reach 100% or when data is get from database it get populated into the results window and progress bar gets closed because work is finished.

Here is code of progress bar , please help me to make template method from it or point me how i can easily do it... i am new in Java and need to your help guys...I hope i will get chance to give +15 to someone

```
//required for activity search results. Activity key column 
will not be displayed
//but data will be stored in here...
hiddenResultValues = new HashMap<String, Vector<String>>();

final Vector<String> columnNames = 
field.getResultColumnNames();

final Vector<Vector<String>> tableContent = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

int size = results.size();
if (size > 0)
{
    final double stepSize = 100 / size;
    //starts long running task off of EDT.
    final Vector<QueryResult<Contact>> resultsFin = results;
    final SearchField fieldFin = field;
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("progress bar example");
            final JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
            service.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int z = 0;
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                    frame.add(progress);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    for(QueryResult<Contact> q : resultsFin)
                    {
                        z = (int) (z + stepSize);
                        final int j = z;
                        progress.setValue(j);
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {


                            }
                        });
                        if(application.isAueTool() && ((q.getQueryResult().getBusinessCategory().contains("K-tronik") 
                                && !q.getQueryResult().getBusinessCategory().contains("AUE")) || (q.getQueryResult().getBusinessCategory().compareTo("Mitarbeiter")==0) || (q.getQueryResult().getBusinessCategory().compareTo("Kandidat")==0)))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        Vector<String> values = new Vector<String>();

                        for(String s : fieldFin.getResultColumns())
                        {
                            values.add(q.getTableEntryForColumn(s));
                        }

                        tableContent.add(values);

                        contacts.add(q.getQueryResult());

                    }

                    // store hidden results
                    for(String s : fieldFin.getHiddenResultColumns())
                        hiddenResultValues.put(s, new Vector<String>());

                    for(QueryResult<Contact> q : resultsFin)
                    {
                        for(String s : fieldFin.getHiddenResultColumns())
                        {
                            hiddenResultValues.get(s).add(q.getTableEntryForColumn(s));
                        }
                    }

                    createTable(tableContent, columnNames, fieldFin);
                    frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please format  the code posted

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the information about [mcve].

Comment: c0der , please take a look one more time at my question . I described everything , i need to take progress bar and make a template method from it or generic method. I don't see the reason why you refer me to section where i need to see how to ask questions.. Please tell me what is not clear to you i will try to explain that detail a bit more.. Thank you so much for your time I hope you know solution for my issue.

Comment: No need to take another look to see that the code is not [mcve]

Comment: c0der, 
I hope you now understand which code i want into template method .. Can you now help me with example so i can make new template methods for other stuff at my code.. I really need it because i want implement it to other methods and classes. Thank you so much.

Comment: @newUserStack Don't you understand what people asked for? [mcve]. So please format your code at least; but you can also organize it in a way others would be able to read it clearly. People are almost ready to help but don't ask them to make the work you can make by yourself. Most of the time, doing it will help you to find the problem by yourself.

Comment: Yes but i can not find solution for it or how it need to be done, I want to fix it alone but i dont know where to start. I hope you will point me how i need to make it done or i don't know what i will do really.